# How do I run my application as superuser from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, client-server, sudo

I'm running in to an error when I try to run my server application from Eclipse. The error is **java.net.BindException: Permission denied**. I think this is because I am using port 443 to set up an SSL connection. I can get around this problem if I run my code on the command line using java and sudo. Is there a way to set up Eclipse so that when I hit the run button, my application is executed with sudo?

Comment: How come `javac` require `sudo` access? you may want to edit the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Like I said in the question I believe it is because I'm trying to bind to port 443 using a SSLServerSocket. I could be wrong though.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, Ronald uses javac to compile and then execute with sudo.
And if the program tries to bind port 443, it could cause problems, as in UNIX/Linux systems any port number below 1024 is reserved for root access.

Comment: Yes, outside of Eclipse I do the following: 1)javac Server.java 2) sudo java Server. This works, but I'd like to keep using Eclipse, so I need to figure out how to make Eclipse run the application as sudo. I'm starting to think this is not possible.

Comment: but the problem isn't `javac`. It's `java` (the executable).

Answer (score 16):

You can follow these steps to compile/debug applications as superuser.

1. Rename your java-application

   sudo mv /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java.ori
2. Create following script and store it as /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > # file:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
   > # descr: Starter for jdk. Runs jdk as root when 
   > #        cmd-line-arg "--run-as-root" is specified.
   > #
   > jre="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java.ori"
   > run_as_root=false
   > args=
   >
   > # Filter command-line argument
   > for arg in "$@"
   > do
   >   case "$arg" in
   >   --run-as-root)  run_as_root=true
   >                   ;;
   >   *)              args="$args $arg"
   >                   ;;
   >
   >   esac
   > done
   >
   > # Remove leading whitespaces
   > args=$(echo $args | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
   >
   > if $run_as_root
   > then
   >   echo "WARNING: Running as root!"
   >   gksu "$jre $args"
   > else
   >   $jre $args
   > fi
   > ```
3. Change the permissions to make it executable

   sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
4. Startup eclipse
5. Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
6. Duplicate java-6-openjdk to java-6-openjdk-root
7. Edit JRE and add "--run-as-root" as Default VM Argument

To run projects as root you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path
2. Double-Click the JRE System Library and choose in Alternate JRE "java-6-openjdk-root"

Note: The idea is from http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/87353/724852/#msg_724852

Comment: for Fedora 19 I managed it to work by using pkexec (without double quotes) instead of gksu: `pkexec $jre $args`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this method, but the following error occurs:
    `Unrecognized option: --run-as-root
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @adrian.nicolau: Please check out my answer again and be sure you followed each step as described. The error you are mentioning occurred probably cause you called the jre directly with `--run-as-root` instead of the bash-script.

Comment: Beautiful! Also consider using the --message option on gksu, otherwise you may get a huge dialog containing a very lengthy command line.

Comment: I have two issues about this solution: 1. it will ask for password (not too bad); 2. it change my project settings somewhere and configuration files cannot be found due a "/root/" was added into the original relative path. I am using Fedora 20.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on Linux (*nix),
How about starting your eclipse session via a sudo command?

Such as

```
sudo ~/eclipse/eclipse
```

Now whatever you do from eclipse will have the sudo context?

Comment: -1 - This is undesirable ... and dangerous. Any files that you write using eclipse will be owned by root. Worse still, since eclipse is running root, it has permission to read, write or delete any file or directory.  Modify or delete the wrong file and you could enter a world of pain.

Comment: Ouch that hurts. I thought I had just answered for exactly what he was looking for. I wouln't sweat all the ifs-and-buts you mentioned when I am on my development box.

Comment: And one more problem in running eclipse in `sudo` mode is that if you want to switch back your eclipse to non-sudo mode later, you will face various problems because eclipsed will not be able to write into various files which are now owned by root. This will result in unspecified eclipse behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg06178.html):

> In order to open a port below 1024 on Unix/Linux systems you need to be
>   "root".
>
> > I also used the argument `-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.port=8080` to change the listen port, but this seems to be ignored (according to the stacktrace)
>
> Please use "`-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8080`".

---

As mentioned in [HTTP Service](http://oscar-osgi.sourceforge.net/repo/http/):

- `org.osgi.service.http.port` - specifies the port number to use for the http serving. The default value for this property is 80 (which requires root permission), as per the OSGi specification.
- **`org.osgi.service.http.port.secure`** - specifies the port number to use for secure http serving. The default value for this property is 443 (which requires root permission), as per the OSGi specification.

Maybe if you try to modify that last property to a value above 1024 it could work without requiring any special privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use iptables or ipfilter to forward port 80 to a port above 1024.

(Can someone contribute a link to a practical and easy-to-understand explanation ?)

Comment: or ssh: love local encrypted tunnels.

Comment: This is a practical link using iptables : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Port80

Answer (score 1):

A better answer, perhaps, if this serves your needs AND is possible, could be simple port redirection on your router.

Instead of trying to force your linux/unix to open a reserved port, when you are only developing this now (not installing) and you want to run it in a debugger, 
set your router to redirect incoming (external) port 443 to a port that is more convenient for your current needs (say 4443).

I think most routers support this, and if yours doesn't it gives your mum a good christmas or birthday present idea!

Comment: whoops, i just realized someone above mentioned the iptable .. same thing. Sorry, not trying to steal your idea!

Answer (score 1):

I am writing C not Java but this should work in either case. 
I use remote debug - define a "remote" connection to LOCALHOST which allows you to specify the user you will connect with, specify ROOT. Then define a Remote Application in debug configuration connection: LOCALHOST. Be sure to check "skip download to target path" at the bottom of the main tab as well as under the connection properties window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Remote Java Application** mechanism for this.

1. Create **Debug configuration** for **Remote Java Application**
   section in **Run -> Debug configurations...**
2. Set your project name
3. Choose **Connection type** as *Standard (Socket Attach)*
4. Configure **Connection properties** parameters for your binding
   (for you it will be *localhost* and *443*).
5. Set breakpoint in your app (e.g. at the beginning of the *main* method)
6. Run your app from terminal as superuser with following command: **java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=443 MyApp**
7. Hit debug button in Eclipse for early created **Remote Java Application**
8. You code should be stopped on breakpoint in Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

If you use External tools (Run menu/External tools or an icon next to the Run/Debug icons on the toolbar), you can use any scripts or whatever you like. The scripts may give you elevated rights, or whatever.

On the other hand, this way debugging the application can become very hard, as neither the Run nor Debug commands get associated with this External tool configuration. Maybe it is possible to connect the Eclipse debugger of the application, but I don't know, how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may go this way

1. create a Makefile with javac calls
2. add the following line:

> ```
> setcap 'cap_net_admin=+ep' Server
> ```

1. configure sudo to allow your Eclipse user to run setcap.

So you will have a transparent debugging (no sudo wrapper - gdb ok).
Cons: it is a local security breach.

Solution:

put this to /opt/my-stupid-eclipse

> #!/bin/sh
>
> setcap 'cap_net_admin=+ep cap_net_raw=+ep' $1

chmod +x this script and whitelist it on sudo config.

> username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/my-stupid-eclipse

Add it to your makefile, specify path to your Server binary.

Now you have pretty strange but secure script, that cannot be changed by other users... and still a little breach for replacing Server binary with any malicious code, that will gain caps, so no filename check/stricts will help.. can $1 be contaminated with bash commands, no? Guess, no.