# Howto debug program that needs to run as root from gdb (Eclipse) as user (set gdb suid root?)

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, suid

I need to debug a program on Linux with Eclipse (gdb). The program run as root and is quite large. The binary with debug symbols is about 250MB large and has more than 60 running threads after startup.

I'm thinking about the best solution:

1. Use gdbserver
2. Run Eclipse as root
3. Set gdb suid

I think number 1 (gdbserver) would be the best solution, unfortunately it's not working reliable. The connection between gdb and gdbserver is lost. I think there is a problem with the huge amount of data transferred between eclipse <-> gdb <-> gdbserver.

Number 2 (run eclipse as root) means to run every process as root and so interferes also with the version control system, because the Eclipse plugin would use the root user instead of mine to change version-controlled files.

I didn't try number 3 (suid gdb). What do you think about it? Does it work at all?
I'm aware that a suid root gdb is as safe as having no root-Password at all, but the machine is used for development and debugging by me only. And of course there could be an "enable/disable" script that sets the suid bit only when necessary.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to debug application as root in eclipse in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891356/how-to-debug-application-as-root-in-eclipse-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

The less intrusive (no need to mess with suid) is to configure yourself to run gdb as root in /etc/sudoers and then just run:

sudo xauth merge ~/.Xauthority

sudo gdb

where the first command is needed to allow root open connection to X server

Answer (score 1):

Either 1) or 3) sound like fine solutions.

The amount of gdb<->gdbserver traffic is never very large. Lost connection implies you are not using reliable transport protocol (which connection protocol *are* you using? have you tried local socket?), or a bug in your version of gdb/gdbserver (which version is it?)

You may also consider 4: change the program to *not* require root permissions in the first place. Any large program will have bugs. Bugs + suid-root => OWND machine. Presumably you'll ship this program to your customers. If they suffer OWND machine, they can go after you for damages.

Usually there is only a very small set of operations which truly require root permissions, and such operations (if sufficiently infrequent) are best performed by a "helper binary" (which is suid-root, but which doesn't run all the time, and is small => less likely to have bugs).

Comment: The term "lost connection" was not right, it looks more like a synchronization problem. There are strange errors in the gdbserver protocol.