# Opening RAW sockets in linux without being superuser

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have to write a ping function to run on Linux. The language is C++, so C if fine too.

Searching on the Internet and looking at the source code for the `ping` command, it turns out that I should create a raw socket:

```
icmp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

If I run my application without being superuser, the `socket` function returns `-1` i.e. the socket is not created successfully. If I run it as a superuser, all works fine.

Now, the `ping` command do create a raw socket and I can run it **without superuser rights**.

My question is: how can I grant my application all permissions needed to create a raw socket without being executed by a superuser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ping` needs the `cap_net_raw` capability to do this without (other) superuser rights, and so does your program. Run

```
setcap cap_net_raw+ep your_executable_file
```

as root, and then normal users will be able to use the program.

Comment: Thank you, It worked! But, if I try to debug it in Eclipse, the socket function returns -1 again. I've tryed to set the cap_new_raw capability both to eclipse and gdb, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah. Yes, debugging programs with capabilities (or that have the suid bit set) is a bit of a problem, because allowing an unprivileged user to `ptrace` them would be a rather big security hole. Perhaps you can configure eclipse to run gdb with sudo, which would allow you to debug the application by diving head-first into the security nightmare of giving an unprivileged user the ability to run a suid debugger. I don't think there's a perfect solution for this problem.

Comment: A workaround I've found is to run eclipse as a superuser. It's not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Ok, opening eclipse with sudo is not a good idea! A better solution is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891356/how-to-debug-application-as-root-in-eclipse-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can make your program a SUID command, granting it effectively root permissions, without granting them to the executing user. For an example and explanation see [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html).

Comment: And still no way to debug SUID programm from non-root, just like with `setcap cap_net_raw+ep`