# tnameserv: Port problems with OSX

Tags: java, distributed-computing, corba, nameservers

How does one use tnameserv on OSX? Everytime I start the server, I get the error below

`(COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 900`

I understand that the ports under 1020 are reserved for root on Mac, but I am the root user on the machine. I can change the port with `-ORBInitialPort 1050` but that would mean changing lots of things in the program.

Comment: It does happen when sudo-ing the command ?

Comment: The nameserver I am trying to run is run from within eclipse IDE, so SUDO may not be an option.

Comment: Ok take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580279/how-do-i-run-my-application-as-superuser-from-eclipse

Comment: Started Eclipse with SUDO and it works! Sadly, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Yeah it could be quite dangerous, but also much more easy than the top answer ^^

Comment: @tuergeist Works, but not the right way to do it.

Comment: I think, refactoring the app to an easy configurable port might be the best option.

Comment: @tuergeist Yup! in the end, that is what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring the application might be the best option. Th port shall be an option to application and can reside in a properties file or a command line option.

Running things, even while development as root or Administrator isn't good designed.