# Error in loading JNI library after sudo authentication in eclipse in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, java-native-interface

I wanted to access device so i have developed one `Java` code in eclipse using `JNI` library which calls c code for communicating with device.

For accessing device we require `sudo` authentication in eclipse so i have done that authentication using the following link

[How do I run my application as superuser from Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580279/how-do-i-run-my-application-as-superuser-from-eclipse)

But right now i am facing the problem in loading JNI libraries in Java code

I am getting error

```
WARNING: Running as root!
Loading...
Did not load library
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at org.sc.ivb.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.<clinit>(DeviceCommunicationController.java:10)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sc.ivb.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.Ivb_InitDevice()V
    at org.sc.ivb.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.Ivb_InitDevice(Native Method)
    at org.sc.ivb.jni.DeviceCommunicationController.main(DeviceCommunicationController.java:27)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `sudo` for this task! Instead, give the appropriate permissions to the device so that the user can access it. This is possible by either using `chmod`/`chown` to change the device file's permissions, or use `adduser <username> <group>` to add the current user to that devices group.