# gksu on Mac Osx

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, macos

im new toward linux command..
Im using Mac Osx Mountain Lion as my operating system and eclipse to compile my java program..

The problem is that im trying to run/compile/debug my java application as root user on eclipse.

Following the step/answer from [rednammoc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277624/rednammoc) in "
[How do I run my application as superuser from Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580279/how-do-i-run-my-application-as-superuser-from-eclipse) "

The step require me  to write a executable script to make my jre to run as root user, however in the script there is a part where it uses the command gksu, which i assume only available on linux platform and not on Mac Osx platform and when i run my program, it show gksu command not found. So the question is,

1. Can I some how install gksu on my Mac Osx?
2. or is there any command that i can use to replace gksu?

Below are the script copied from the link,

```
#!/bin/bash
# file:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
# descr: Starter for jdk. Runs jdk as root when 
#        cmd-line-arg "--run-as-root" is specified.
#
jre="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java.ori"
run_as_root=false
args=

# Filter command-line argument
for arg in "$@"
do
  case "$arg" in
  --run-as-root)  run_as_root=true
                  ;;
  *)              args="$args $arg"
                  ;;

  esac
done

# Remove leading whitespaces
args=$(echo $args | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')

if $run_as_root
then
  echo "WARNING: Running as root!"
  gksu "$jre $args"
else
  $jre $args
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any command that i can use to replace gksu?

```
osascript -e 'on run argv' \
          -e 'do shell script (item 1 of argv) with administrator privileges' \
          -e 'end run' \
          "$jre $args"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just found this over at http://pastebin.com/dhbU57uE haven't tried it yet, though!

```
#!/bin/bash
# file:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
# descr: Starter for jdk. Runs jdk as root when 
#        cmd-line-arg "--run-as-root" is specified.
#
jre="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java.ori"
run_as_root=false
args=

# Filter command-line argument
for arg in "$@"
do
  case "$arg" in
  --run-as-root)  run_as_root=true
                  ;;
  *)              args="$args $arg"
                  ;;

  esac
done

# Remove leading whitespaces
args=$(echo $args | sed -e 's/^[ t]*//')

if $run_as_root
then
  echo "WARNING: Running as root!"
  gksu "$jre $args"
else
  $jre $args
fi

osascript -e 'on run argv' 
          -e 'do shell script (item 1 of argv) with administrator privileges' 
          -e 'end run' 
          "$jre $args"
```

Comment: Nope. This does nothing. Ugh. Wish I understood what the heck the osascript answer above from Ian is trying to explain...