# sudo an application asking the user with a dialog?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, admin, sudo

I'd like to run an OSX application with admin privileges, so the user would be asked first for his admin log/pass.
Is there a bash command or an applescript command that would allow me to do that ?

Sort of a sudo command but with a graphic dialog shown to the user, similar to what the Finder shows when asking permission to write files in restricted folders.

thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378162/gksu-on-mac-osx

Comment: Write a privileged helper in Cocoa. Anything else is insecure and a kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(if by OSX application are you talking about the applescript one?)

In applescript, you can display a dialog that finder displays for the users login and password but this will not tell you the password, it will basically run a shell script as sudo:

```
do shell script "myadminshellcommand arguments" with administrator privileges
```

By adding "with administrator privileges" you are telling AppleScript to run a shell script in sudo with the users password

```
(Don't add sudo to the command)
```

Answer (score 0):

to carry an application on any Mac, you have to ask for password

```
tell application "System Events"
    set fullname to full name of current user
end tell
display dialog fullname & "  Enter your password " default answer "" with hidden answer
set the adminpass to the text returned of the result
set PW to result
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (fullname & " " & PW) user name fullname password PW with administrator privileges
tell application "System Events"
    set TheUse to ("/Users/" & name of current user & "/Desktop/")


end tell
```