# Ubuntu GKSU Java System.err.println() not working

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have a very simple program here:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("HI");
    }
}
```

When I execute this with the following command: `gksu "java Test.class"` and enter in my password, it does not return "HI" as expected. What am I doing wrong here? I am stumped.
The reason I am using `gksu` and not just normal `java` is because I want to launch my program as root from eclipse. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580279/how-do-i-run-my-application-as-superuser-from-eclipse) answer and this is my outcome. My original program is a lot bigger than this. This is just a demo to display the problem.

Comment: Isn't that for graphical commands? I'd expect it would be swallowing both stdout and stderr, but maybe it doesn't.

Comment: @Dave Newton `System.out.println("HI");` works just fine

Comment: Added my reason for using `gksu` instead of normal `java`

Comment: Same behavior if you use sudo instead of gksu?

Comment: `sudo` outputs "HI" unlike `gksu`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced gksu is what you'd want to use for a non-graphical program.

Comment: It is a graphical program, I am just using this program for a demo for this site. Using the original program, `System.err.println()` does not work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58456/discussion-between-christopher-smith-and-dave-newton).